# Change where conditions based on column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new in sql and i try to change my where conditions based on a column value in my select from Orcale table, like bellow:

```
Select 
a 
,b
,c
,date_time
from t
where 
condition_1
or condition_2
```

so the condition_2 is i want to check if the date_time column is like '**date 00:00:00**' so
i will do

```
to_date(to_char(date_time,'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'yyyy-mm-dd') **>=** 
to_date(to_char(to_date('2022-01-01 11:11:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

if not then i will do this condition

```
date_time **>** to_date('2022-01-01 11:11:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

i tried to do it with case when inside my where but can not find the good logical way.

Can anyone help me please!
Thanks

Comment: These conditions look very strange. Could you please show some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Sorry i modified the first condition that i want to use, it is complicate to do sample data exemple.

Comment: Your first condition can be simplified to `trunc(date_time) >= date '2022-01-01'`. But anything that fails that must also fail the second one, surely?

Comment: I don't understand why you want two conditions? your second condition will always be true if the first condition is met? You want rows where the date_col is greater or equal to the start of the specified day, or you want rows where the date_col is greater than the start of the day after the specified day? Rows meeting the second condition will automatically meet the first condition! Also, you don't have to convert dates to chars to dates again in order to remove the time part - you can use `trunc(<date>)` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time seeing wat you want to do with the condition example but based on the question if we want to switch depending on b:

```
Select 
a 
,b
,c
,date_time
from t
where 
  (b = 1 && condition_1) 
  or 
  (b = 2 && condition_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear what was the question about. We can split it to some parts.

1. Sample data

| A | B | C | DATE_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | bbb | ccc | 31.01.2022 11:59:59 |
| ddd | eee | fff | 28.02.2022 00:00:00 |
| ggg | hhh | iii | 24.12.2021 00:00:00 |
| jjj | wkkk | lll | 12.01.2022 22:01:10 |

*1st quote from question* ***"I want to check if the date_time column is like 'date 00:00:00'"***
If we want to see which rows have time part of the DATE_TIME column **= 00:00:00**

```sql
Select  A, B, C, DATE_TIME, To_Char(DATE_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') "TIME_PART"
From    tbl
Where   DATE_TIME = TRUNC(DATE_TIME)
```

| A | B | C | DATE_TIME | TIME_PART |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ddd | eee | fff | 28-FEB-22 | 00:00:00 |
| ggg | hhh | iii | 24-DEC-21 | 00:00:00 |

2nd quote ***"if not then i will do this condition date_time **>** to_date('2022-01-01 11:11:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')"***
let's try just this condition:

```sql
Select  A, B, C, DATE_TIME, To_Char(DATE_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') "TIME_PART"
From    tbl
Where   DATE_TIME > To_Date('2022-01-01 11:11:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

| A | B | C | DATE_TIME | TIME_PART |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | bbb | ccc | 31-JAN-22 | 11:59:59 |
| ddd | eee | fff | 28-FEB-22 | 00:00:00 |
| jjj | kkk | lll | 12-JAN-22 | 22:01:10 |

It is clear that if we use OR between above two conditions, the result will be the same as no condition at all - all rows will be returned.
On the other hand, if we use AND between them...

```sql
Select  A, B, C, DATE_TIME, To_Char(DATE_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss') "TIME_PART"
From    tbl
Where   DATE_TIME > To_Date('2022-01-01 11:11:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
        DATE_TIME = TRUNC(DATE_TIME)
```

Then there will be just one row as a result:

| A | B | C | DATE_TIME | TIME_PART |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ddd | eee | fff | 28-FEB-22 | 00:00:00 |

I don't know if this is of any help but that is all I could offer...